# TestCafe skips clicking steps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, e2e-testing, testcafe

Successfully authenticates, but I don't understand why, for some reason skips clicking on the drop menu and suddenly closes the browser window.

Can anyone know why the test skips clicking on the drop menu here?

```
import LoginModel from './page-models/Login';
const url = 'http://localhost:5000';
fixture('Login tests - Logged In')
  .page(url)
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await LoginModel.userLogin(t);
  });
  test('Should show the drop menu', async t => {
    await t.expect(LoginModel.dropMenu.exists).ok();
  });
test('Should show the logout button after logging in', async t => {
  await t.expect(LoginModel.logoutButton.exists).ok();
});
fixture('Login tests - Not logged in').page(url);
test('Should have a username and password field', async t => {
  await t.wait(10000);
  await t.expect(LoginModel.username.exists).ok();
  await t.expect(LoginModel.password.exists).ok();
});
```

page object model:

```
class Login {
    username: Selector = Selector('[id=userEmail]');
    password: Selector = Selector('[id=userPassword]');
    loginButton: Selector = Selector('[id=login-button]');
    dropMenu: Selector = Selector('[id=simple-menu]');
    logoutButton: Selector = Selector('[id=logout-button]');
    async userLogin(t: TestController) {
      await t
        .typeText(this.username, 'user', { replace: true, paste: true })
        .typeText(this.password, 'pass', { replace: true, paste: true })
        .click(this.loginButton);
    }
    async userClickDropMenu(t: TestController) {
      await t
        .click(this.dropMenu);
    }
    async userLogout(t: TestController) {
      await t
        .click(this.logoutButton);
    }
  }   
export default new Login();
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where the required `click(LoginModel.dropMenu)` action should be placed? I cannot see it in your code snippet.

Comment: @DmitryOstashev updated, this action should be after login action

Comment: Now I see the action in the page model, but the `userClickDropMenu` method is not called in the test. What do you see in the browser window during test execution? Does TestCafe try to click the drop menu (e.g. a pointer moves to this element and hovers over it)? You can add the `await t.debug()` action at the end of the test to prevent the browser window from closing. If the click occurs without any result, we need to research it further. Please create a simple webpage or give us a website public url that we can use to reproduce this behavior.